# Import txt file with empty line at the end and special characters

Tags: import

I want to import txt file with empty line at the end and special characters. I tried many options from the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/Text.html). `"String"` option detects the empty line but it does not recognise special characters.

```
file = ParentDirectory@$UserDocumentsDirectory<>"\\Downloads\\nekineki.txt";

Export[file,"123 abc \n"];
SystemOpen@file;

Import@file
Import[file,"String"]
```

Out:

[image]

What is the right way to import this?

I'm using Mathematica 13.1 and Windows 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the trailing `"\n"` is being dropped.  I have a verbose workaround.

```
expStr = ExportString["123 abc \n", "Text"];
```

Then

```
StringJoin[
 StringRiffle[
  ImportString[#, "Text"] & /@
   StringSplit[
    ImportString[expStr, "String"]
    , "\n", All]
  , "\n"
  ]
 ]
```

> ```
> "123 abc 
> "
> ```

As I said it is verbose; room for improvement.

Comment: This isn't a workaround for a dropped `\n`, but rather forces a `\n` to the end of every read file. Even files that don't have a final `\n` will receive one here.

Answer (score 2):

On macOS it works via [`ReadByteArray`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReadByteArray.html) and [`ByteArrayToString`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ByteArrayToString.html):

```
file = "\\tmp\\nekineki.txt";

Export[file, "123 abc \n"];

ByteArrayToString[ReadByteArray[file]]
(*    "123 abc \n"    *)
```

We can define a reader function:

```
myread = ByteArrayToString@*ReadByteArray;

myread[file]
(*    "123 abc \n"    *)
```

Or, following @GalZoidberg's advice, for Windows we can do

```
myread = StringDelete["\r"]@*ByteArrayToString@*ReadByteArray;
```

to make sure we don't end up with [lingering `\r\n` patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1761051).

Comment: This also works. On windows it's just a slight difference, so you do `StringDelete[myread[file], "\r"]` at the end.